# Making Wookmark jQuery order divs properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay so I am wanting to use the jQuery plugin "Wookmark" to display data from a database in numerical order. But they are displaying it in this order: [image]

and as you can tell they are displaying right to left, then after four rectangles, left to right. How could I get it to display in numerical order like so:

[ 1] [2] [3] [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8]

I'm not sure how to fix this, so maybe check out the GitHub here: https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery

Comment: I use Masonry instead. http://masonry.desandro.com/ . You can consider it

Comment: are you saying that size is irrelevant to placement? Strictly use left to right order? If so can be done with css or a few lines of code to make column wrappers assuming widths are all the same as shown

Comment: I took a look at the file. It positions the next item based on the shortest previous block. Based on it's design, the shortest block will always be the every fourth block. You could change the code `left: (shortestIndex*columnWidth + offset)+'px'` and check to see if the sum of the previous indices +1 *(because they're zero based)* are divisible by 4. You can check using the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).