# Making the jQuery plugin "Wookmark" display divs left to right?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Wookmark jQuery order divs properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028347/making-wookmark-jquery-order-divs-properly)

I am wanting to use the jQuery plugin "Wookmark" availiable here: https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery

And I am wanting it to display from left to right on each row but instead it is displaying it as:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[7] [8] [6] [5]
```

Instead of this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8]
```

I want it to display right to left no mater the content that is in the cells. Sorry for not explaining this the best, but I am not very good with words. But pretty much I want the cells to display left to right no matter what and still work.

Thank you.

Comment: **Do not** repost unanswered questions.

Comment: Sorry I thought I accedently deleted the previous post. I'm still getting used to StackOverflow. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using any plugin you can give css float:left to your list item and make container width 100% so your list will come on same order.
Following css  can help you.

```
.container{
width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    left:0px;

}


.container li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

check on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sudhanshu414/3GVxT/

If you need somthing different tell me.

And make sure if you are using float left, than in next element to container add css clear:both if you dont want it to be floated with your previous elements.

Comment: I want it to order correctly using the plugin not that, its jQuery issue not a css one